# Use plugin given Vue constructor for component inheritance with vue-component-class

Tags: typescript, inheritance, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-class-components

I have a plugin that create multiple globally available components, these components access instance properties set by other plugins in the main app. In most Typescript examples, people get their Vue constructor by `import { Vue } from 'vue'` or `import { Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'`however I'd like to use the vue constructor that is passed down to my plugin. How would you do that?

Here is my attempt which does not work sadly. I know it works without using classes but that's not the point.

```js
// app/main.ts

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import { MyComponentsPlugin } from 'my-components-plugin';

import App from './App';

Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.use(MyComponentsPlugin);

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

```js
// my-components-plugin/main.ts

import { VueConstructor } from 'vue';

import MyComponentExport from './components/MyComponent/Component.vue';

export async function MyComponentsPlugin(
  vue: VueConstructor,
  options?: any,
): Promise<void> {
  vue.component('MyComponent', MyComponentExport(vue));
}
```

```js
// my-components-plugin/components/Component.vue

<template>
  <p>toto</p>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { VueConstructor } from 'vue';
import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

export default function(Vue: VueConstructor) {
 @Component
  class Header extends Vue {
    private mounted() {
      console.log(this.$vuetify);
    }
  }

  return Header;
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

Comment: Jonas did You find answer?

Comment: Yeah i'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue, you need to update your `webpack` config in your `vue.config.js`. Add:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      config.resolve.modules.prepend(path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'));
    }
  },
};
```

This way your project dependencies will search first into your project local `node_modules` to find their dependencies hence they will use the same `Vue` as the main application.

We don't need to add it for production environment because the bundles will be optimized and `Vue` code duplication will be prevented.